Unable to Attach Multiple Security Groups to a Single Network Load Balancer in AWS API Gateway
I'm trying to set up a Network Load Balancer (NLB) in AWS and associate it with multiple security groups. I'm using AWS CloudFormation with a YAML template to configure the NLB. However, I encounter an issue where the NLB does not seem to associate with more than one security group.
Example
Here is what I have tried so far:

Created a Network Load Balancer using the AWS Management Console.
Attempted to attach multiple security groups to the NLB.

Resources:
  MyNetworkLoadBalancer:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::LoadBalancer
    Properties:
      Name: my-nlb
      Type: network
      Subnets:
        - subnet-0abc123456def7890
        - subnet-0abc123456def7891
      SecurityGroups:
        - sg-0abc123456def7890
        - sg-0abc123456def7891

  MyTargetGroup:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup
    Properties:
      Name: my-target-group
      Port: 80
      Protocol: TCP
      VpcId: vpc-0abc123456def7890

  MyListener:
    Type: AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::Listener
    Properties:
      DefaultActions:
        - Type: forward
          TargetGroupArn: !Ref MyTargetGroup
      LoadBalancerArn: !Ref MyNetworkLoadBalancer
      Port: 80
      Protocol: TCP


What I Tried:

Verified that the subnets and security groups exist and are properly configured.
Ensured that the VPC is correctly set up.
Attempted to manually associate the security groups through the AWS Management Console, which works, but not through the CloudFormation template.

I expected the NLB to be created with both security groups (sg-0abc123456def7890 and sg-0abc123456def7891) associated with it as specified in the YAML file. This should allow the NLB to follow the rules defined in both security groups.

Hi! i answer here because this inst a direct answer to your question. The good practice is setting a single security group for each of your balancers and giving it access to the other sgs via inbound rules. btw, you can try giving it access through the console and look at the error there
